# Access a Hive table using `PyHive` with numbers on the beginning of the table name gives error

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyhive

I'm using `PyHive` to access my Hive server:

```
# Connection parameters
hive_host = "server.redecorp.com"
hive_port = 10000
hive_options = {'job.queue.name': 'myqueue'}

connection = hive.Connection(host=hive_host, port=hive_port, configuration=hive_options)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

and it works:

```
cursor.execute('show databases')
cursor.fetchall()

----
my_database
default
----
```

If I try to access a table or database with a number on the beginning of the table I get an error:

```
cursor.execute('select * from my_database.2016_my_table')
```

gives me

```
OperationalError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1e42ea2af711> in <module>()


OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=1, errorMessage='Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask', sqlState='08S01', infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask:29:28', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:314', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runQuery:SQLOperation.java:146', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:173', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:256', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:376', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:357', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor184:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:79', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:37', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:64', 'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2', 'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415', 'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1628', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure:doAs:HadoopShimsSecure.java:536', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:60', 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23:executeStatement::-1', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:234', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:401', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1313', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1298', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:206', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745'], statusCode=3), operationHandle=None)
```

Does anyone knows a workaround or a fix for this? I can't change the name of the tables.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Are you using tez as the execution engine? Try setting it to mr in the hive options 'hive.execution.engine': 'mr'. If MR is not a feasible option for you then try increasing the container size in the hive options 'hive.tez.container.size': '3072' - (memory in MB). This probably happens because of memory constraint issues. Increasing the hive container size while initiating the connection solved this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the table name, the problem is that you are using `select * from database.2016_my_table` but the database is named `default` so it should be `select * from default.2016_my_table`.

Comment: I cleared the names of the tables for the sake of the post. It is definitely not default.

Comment: What version of Hive are you using? I tried creating and accessing tables with names starting with numbers and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Hive 0.14. The interesting bit is that everything works with hive cli and beeline.